# Universal wave function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, quantum-interpretations

Doesn't the existence of a Universal wave function allow one to extract a preferred space time foliation?

There are plenty of papers that try and derive the preferred space time foliation from BM interpretation and its universal wave function one of the main criticisms is that that goes against GR.

Why isn't the same said about MWI, is the universal wave function different there or what?

Example of one using the universal wave function to select a foliation:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1101.4575.pdf

EDIT: Bohmian Mechanics= BM, Many world Interpretation= MWI, GR=General relativity

Comment: Could you define the acronyms as not everybody may be familiar with them?

Comment: @fgoudra done, done and done